# Semi-decidable problems with linear bound

Tags: computability, time-complexity, undecidability

Take a semi-decidable problem and an algorithm that finds the positive answer in finite time. The run-time of the algorithm, restricted to inputs with a positive answer, cannot be bounded by a computable function. (Otherwise we’d know how long to wait for a positive answer. If the algorithm runs longer than that we know that the answer is no and the problem would be solvable.)

My question is now: Can such an algorithm still have a, say, a run-time bound linear (polynomial, constant,...) in the input size, but with an uncomputable constant? Or would that still allow me to decide the problem? Are there example?

Comment: What's an "uncomputable constant"? A constant is just one number, and thus is a finite amount of information, and thus is trivially "computable". We normally talk about *families of problems* being computable or uncomputable, not *values*.

Comment: I guess what I mean is a constant that is unknown, and where the problem of deciding whether a given number is the constant in question is undecidable. According to Raphaels comment, this is not what “computable” means. I wonder if I should fix the question, but fixing it would basically answer it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your sketched decision algorithm to work, it is sufficient that the run-time is *majorized* by a computable function. Every linear function $n \mapsto c\cdot n$ even for non-computable c is majorized by a computable function, viz., $n \mapsto \lceil c \rceil \cdot n$. Thus the answer to the question is no: a semi-decision procedure for an undecidable problem cannot have linear run-time (or a run-time majorized by any computable function.)

Comment: Thanks. Its still not clear to me how I would find  ⌈c⌉, can you elaborate?

Comment: Let me elaborate this question: It seems that finding ⌈c⌉ itself is not decidable: Given a natural k, there seems to be no way to check if n↦k⋅n is indeed a bound.

Maybe I should have not said “uncomputable constant“ in the original question, but rather more vaguely “unknown constant”.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: That's the "[$\pi$-paradoxon](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-can-it-be-decidable-whether-pi-has-some-sequence-of-digits)": the *existence* of a computable majorizing function is enough (for the *existence* of a decision procedure). We don't have to be able to write it down.

Comment: So in summary: We know that there exists an algorithm to decide the problem (so the problem is decidable), but the problem of finding such an algorithm is undecidable. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: That is not the claim ("we don't know it" != "algorithmically undecidable"), but I think it's true.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot bound it. Assume you have a characterization of your bound, in terms of a function. That can be a polynomial, exponential, linear etc. We will denote that function by $f(n)$. Since we work on a deterministic setting, we can define an appropriate class $DTIME(f(n))$. Here note that we get a bound on the number of steps which will be a natural number whereas the bound might be not. We can get past such technicalities as @Jan Johannsen describes in his post. What is important is that **all** deterministic classes are closed under complement, thus all problems in them are decidable. Thus, so will be the semi-decidable problem under consideration, a contradiction.