# What's an intuitive distinction between semi-computable problems and noncomputable problems/functions?

Tags: computability, terminology

The definitions I've found were highly technical and using terms I've never seen before.

Say, I have a certain irrational number *e* that I get get closer and closer to with a computer and I want to determine if there is a particular digit *d* appearing after a certain position. Or what about the halting problem (give a program and ask 'will the computer ever halt?')? Are these problems semi-computable problems or noncomputable?

Comment: "The definitions I've found were highly technical and using terms I've never seen before" -- In my experience, it is worthwhile to sit down and learn the basics first. Otherwise, you are likely to have trouble understanding the concepts as many of them are inherently formal-theoretic resp. abstract.

Comment: For the problem with $e$, see also [this related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-can-it-be-decidable-whether-pi-has-some-sequence-of-digits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, a set of numbers is *computable* or *decidable* or *recursive* if there is an algorithm deciding membership for the set. A set of numbers is *semidecidable* or *recursively enumerable* (r.e.) if it has verifiable "proofs" of membership. For example, the set of programs which halt is semidecidable, since given a program $A$ and a time bound $t$, one can check that $A$ halts after at most $t$ steps. But this set is not computable, since without the time bound, we don't know how long to wait for. (That's an intuitive explanation; you can google for a proof that the halting problem is not decidable.)

There are several equivalent definitions of semidecidable sets:

- A set $S$ is semidecidable if there exists an algorithm $A$ which always terminates with either YES or NO as an answer, such that $x \in S$ iff there is a witness $w$ for which $A(x,w)$ answers YES.
- A set $S$ is semidecidable if there exists an algorithm $A$ such that $x \in S$ iff $A(x)$ halts.
- A set $S$ is semidecidable if there is an algorithm that enumerates all members of $S$.

See if you can show that all these definitions are equivalent. You might want to look up the technique of "dovetailing".

What about the digits of $e$? We need to phrase the problem of computing the digits of $e$ in our framework. The set of digits of $e$ is the set of pairs $(k,d)$, where $d$ is the $k$th decimal digit of $e=2.71828\ldots$, i.e. $\{(0,2),(1,7),(2,1),(3,8),(4,2),(5,8),\ldots\}$. Since there is an algorithm computing the $k$th digit of $e$ (e.g. using the Taylor series $e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/k!$), the set of digits of $e$ (under this encoding) is computable.

Edit: Following the OP's comment, suppose we're interested in the set of positions $n$ such that the decimal expansion of $e$ contains the digit $2$ somewhere past the $n$th digit. This set is decidable, for the following reason: either the digit $2$ appears infinitely often, or its last appearance is at digit $N$. In the first case, the set in question contains all natural numbers, in the second case it is $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$.

The same trick works for any fixed real number. Consider, however, the set consisting of pairs $(A,n)$ such that $A$ is an algorithm that enumerates the decimal expansion of some real number, which contains the digit $2$ somewhere past the $n$th digit. This set is *not* computable, only semidecidable, since one can reduce the halting problem to it and vice versa (how?).

Comment: thanks for your Interesting answer. I didnt know that a program can be semidecidable and noncomputable at the same time (the Halting problem). regarding e, i was referring to an arbitrary irrational number e not the particular Euler number, and the program should return true if after a certain decimal digit there is an occurence of the digit '2' say. and it might never stop...so, this would be not decideable, since algortihm A might never terminate (irrational number that has .11 repeating to infinity and we're looking for a 2)

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I was not familiar with the property that after the nth decimal digit, a particular digit cannot appear only once.

Comment: @sdfasdgasg "I didnt know that a program can be semidecidable and noncomputable at the same time (the Halting problem)" -- that is wrong on so many levels! Computability is a property of *problems*, not programs. If the problem is undecidable, *there is no program* that solves it.  Some undecidable problems can be semi-decided, so that's when you can't have a decider but you have a semi-decider.

Comment: The first paragraph is misleading. The first two sentences give, in some sense, circular intuition. The second part mixes in a time bound, which imho muddies the distinction between deciding and semi-deciding. (The rest of the answer is fine.)

Comment: @Raphael: I appreciate your sharp insights. Random note just opped into my mind: Why is it that Halting is not decidable AND in NP hard? I thought you can only place computable problems into any complexity class..

Comment: @sdfasdgasg The Halting program is NP-hard because there are no time constraints on the programs involved. For that matter, it is also PSPACE-hard. But you're right that the comparison doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Raphael I was trying to give intuition. The concept of semidecidability suddenly appears quite arbitrary... Perhaps its recursively enumerable nature is more natural.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I understand; I felt that if I, having understoof the underlying concept somehwat, was confused while reading the paragraph, it might not help a novice. Imho, decidability is something not really suited to be done without formal definitions.