# Why is the halting problem decidable for LBA?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, undecidability, halting-problem, linear-bounded-automata

I have read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Common_pitfalls) and some other texts that

> The halting problem is [...] decidable for [linear bounded
>   automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton) (LBAs) [and] deterministic machines with finite memory.

But earlier it is written that the halting problem is an undecidable problem and thus TM can't solve it! Since LBA are defined as a type of TM, should the same not hold for them?

Comment: You can use a TM to determine if a LBA halts on a given input by checking if it halts in, say, O(2^2^n) steps by simulation. Any LBA working for longer than that is stuck in an infinite loop. This isn't saying LBAs can solve the halting problem for general TMs!

Comment: Finite automata are also a type of TM.

Comment: @Raphael You cannot edit questions like that. You changed the meaning of the question, thus making my existing answer out of topic, while the other answer was out of topic and is now in topic.

Comment: @babou I don't see how I changed the meaning of the question, and I don't see how either of the two questions was not answering the question (even though they use different approaches).

Comment: @Rap The original question is more about logical discourse than about
formal justification of LBA properties, and that is what you removed
from the title. To me it is clear that, though it might be proved that
halting is decidable for LBAs, the OP is wondering how it can be
compatible with other statements regarding inclusion of LBAs in TMs
and undecidability of halting for TMs (can I edit back?).
BTW no intent to disparage Yuval's answer. I expect he
will get most of the votes, because that is what the readership is
after (which is a pedagogical problem in itself), even if I will not
indulge.

Comment: @babou I don't read the original question that way (obviously, otherwise I would not have edited), I thought it was merely worded badly. Anyway, I don't think it matters: your answer is okay for the question as it is (even though it does not actually answer why HP for LBA is decidable).

Comment: @Raphael Not trying to over-edit you. I was about to edit with the reference when you did it, as I found the quote a bit strange. Maybe Wikipedia needs some editing too :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The halting problem is solvable for any Turing machine which uses a known bounded amount of space, by a generalization of the argument given by Yonatan N. If the amount of space is $S$, the alphabet size is $A$, and the number of states is $Q$, then the number of possible configurations is $QSA^S$. If the machine halts then it must halt within $QSA^S$ steps, since otherwise, by the pigeonhole principle, it has a repeated configuration and so is stuck in an infinite loop. Therefore to determine whether the machine halts, we just run it for $QSA^S$ steps and see whether it halts within that time frame.

Comment: Why does that argument work for non-deterministic machines?

Comment: Due to Savitch's theorem.

Comment: I did not know (or remember) of Savitch's theorem other than the name
(I never did much complexity). But I am not sure it can be used that
way, as it applies to decision procedures, i.e. halting computations,
while decidability of halting is precisely what must be proved. The
proof could be adapted to include space-bounded semi-decisions, but it
seems simpler to prove separately that halting is decidable for
space-bounded TM, thus turning space-bounded semi-decisions into full
decisions. This is close to what is done by Hopcroft-Ullman-79 in
their lemma 12-1, before proving Savitch's theorem.

Comment: My own idea is to use a dynamic programming argument,
simulating all ND computations to find all the reachable
configurations (finite in number as you show), and check whether one
of them is halting. This must terminate, and is thus a decision
procedure. - - - - - - Hopcroft-Ullman-79, in lemma 12-1, has a nice
way of proving termination can be forced on ND computations: any configuration that can
be reached with more than $QSA^S$ steps can also be reached with a
smaller number of steps. Hence, any ND computation that has not accepted
the input after $QSA^S$ steps may be halted.

Comment: The simulation in Savitch's theorem is more efficient, but your method works as well. As for using Savitch's theorem, you can use the construction there to simulate the LBA using a deterministic $O(n^2)$-space machine, and then proceed as indicated in my answer.

Comment: What I meant is that your very terse comment may be misleading for the
readership. Not knowing Savitch's theorem myself, I tried to just
apply it and could not find how. Then I went to the proof and realized
that you had that construction in mind, rather than using the theorem itself. This construction
does take less space than dynamic programming, though a lot more time,
for what it matters.

Comment: How is the given argument specific to deterministic TMs?

Comment: @reinierpost It's not. It should work even for non-deterministic TMs with bounded time or space.

Comment: I might be me misunderstanding this, but is the answer to literally run the program, and see if it gets stuck in an infinite loop or not?

Comment: @TrentonMaki Yea, that's exactly so.

Answer (score 10):

**You seem stuck with a logical problem.**

From the fact that there are books that you cannot read, you cannot
infer that you cannot read any book.

Saying that the halting problem is undecidable for Turing Machines (TM)
only means that there are machines for which there is no way to determine
whether they halt or not by some uniform procedure that will always halt.

However there are Turing Machines that do halt.  Now take a subset of
Turing Machines, called the Nice Turing Machines (NTM), such that it
contains only Turing Machines that do halt if and only if the tape
contains an even number of symbols. If a machine M is known to be from
that set, you have a simple way to decide whether M will halt: you
check whether the number of tape symbols is even (it requires only two
fingers).

But that procedure will not work for TM that are not in the NTM set. (too bad!)

So the halting problem is decidable for the NTM, but not for the TM in
general, even though the NTM set is included in the TM set.

**This is actually critical, and sometimes forgotten, when interpreting
undecidability result.**

It may well be that one can prove that an important property is
undecidable for a very large family of mathematical  or computational
objects.

This does not mean that you should stop looking for a solution, but
only that you will not find one for the whole family.

What you may then do is identify relevant subfamilies for which
solving the problem remains important, and try to provide algorithms
to decide whether the property holds for members of that smaller
family.

Typically, halting is undecidable for TM in general, but it is
decidable, often very simply, for large and useful families of
automata, which can all be seen as special cases of TM.

Comment: "Saying that the halting problem is undecidable for Turing Machines (TM) only means that there are machines for which there is no way to determine whether they halt or not by some procedure that will always halt." -- Not quite true. For any given TM, the halting problem is decidable. It's the general decision problem that's undecidable, i.e. there is no *one* algorithm that deals with *all* TMs. (I think this has to be made very, very clear for beginners. Cf the [pi problem](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-can-it-be-decidable-whether-pi-has-some-sequence-of-digits).)

Comment: A more immediate example is the set of all TMs that always hold. Your's adds some extra flavor because it lies outside of the normal hierarchy.

Comment: Right. I should have said "uniform procedure", but it was implicit in my mind as
I said "procedure that will always halt" implying that I can use it on
any input, meaning any machine. But it is true that a procedure could work
correctly for one machine, and do anything for other machines. Well
... - - - - - - - - Regarding the second comment, that is what I wrote at
first. I then changed my mind because I thought my example would be
easier to understand intuitively, as the selection of machines does not
rely as directly on the property to be decided (though it is close).

Answer (score 2):

In short, A LBA has finite number of configurations, say D. Hence, we can run for D steps and conclude the result. If it runs for more that D steps, by pigeonhole principle, we can say that, it is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: What does this add over [the existing answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/22926/755)?   This seems to just repeat it, in less detail.  While I appreciate that you are trying to contribute, we'd prefer that you avoid repeating existing answers and instead focus on answering questions that don't already have a good answer.