# complement of a NON RECURSIVELY ENUMERABLE LANGUAGE

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

Define languages L0 and L1 as follows :

L0={⟨M,w,0⟩∣M halts on w}

L1={⟨M,w,1⟩∣M does not halt on w}

Here ⟨M,w,i⟩is a triplet, whose first component M is an encoding of a Turing 
Machine, second component w is a string, and the third component i is a bit.

Let L= L0 ∪ L1. Which of the following is true?

L is not even recursively enumerable as we cannot even design an acceptor for L as even when 
L0 is RE L1 is not RE

but can anyone explain me what about 
L COMPLEMENT what is the language ??

L0'={⟨M,w,0⟩∣M doesn't halts on w}

L1'={⟨M,w,1⟩∣M halts on w} what i am working on is will there be any such encodings which satisfy both for the intersection to be non empty if there are no such encodings the set becomes empty and hence regular right ? please help

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: sure sir i will change it

Comment: @Raphael sir please help me understand the complement of this language ..

Answer (score 2):

The complement of $L$ is $$\overline{L_0 \cup L_1} = \overline{L_0} \cap \overline{L_1}$$ 
where $\overline{L_0} = \{D \mid \text{ if } D \text{ is } \langle M,w,0\rangle \text{ then } M(w) \text{ does not halt}\}$. In other words, $\overline{L_0}$ consists of those triples $\langle M,w,b\rangle$ which does not include descriptions $\langle M,w,0\rangle$ such that $M$ halts on $w$. Similarly for $\overline{L_1}$. [This post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80924/is-the-below-language-non-r-e/80947#80947) explains why both $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are not recursively enumerable.

Comment: sir i understood the proof for L but what is L complement just give a hint ..

Comment: thanks for bearing a lot of patience i am actually a very beginner in this concepts and i think these are tough for beginners like me . i was not thaught these concepts in my college sorry to disturb .u people are experts in ur fields i spent a lot of time from yesterday on understanding this L' but couldnt  what my doubt is if we take the complement of L in form of set notation which is L1' intersection L2'  which can be even a empty set right ? how can we gaurentee that the intersection in this case in nonempty set and please explain how this set is generated  sorry to disturb

Comment: Let $U$ be a universal set. In particular take $U = \Sigma = \{0,1\}$. For any two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $U$ the following two equalities are always true: 1) $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ and 2) $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$. These equalities are known as [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). You can spend some time to prove them (which is a simple exercise) to convince yourself. Furthermore, $\overline{A}$ is empty iff $A=U$ (is a universal set).

Comment: Also if $A$ and $B$ have no common elements then their intersection is also is empty.

Comment: yes sir i understood that part but as this language contains encodings of the form L0'={⟨M,w,0⟩∣M doesn't halts on w} and                                         L1'={⟨M,w,1⟩∣M halts on w}  what i am asking is will there be any such encodings which satisfy both for the intersection to be non empty if there are no such encodings the set becomes empty and hence regular right ?

Comment: It depends on your encoding. Let $T$ be a set of all pairs $\langle M,w \rangle$ (over $0$ and $1$). Next define a new set $S = T\times \{0,1\}$, which is essentially a set of all triplets $\langle M,w, b\rangle$ (where $b=0$ or $1$). Then the intersection $\overline{L_0} \cap \overline{L_1}$ is not empty. But if you define your universal set as the union of $L_0 \cup L_1$ then the intersection $\overline{L_0} \cap \overline{L_1}$ is of course empty. But in both cases $L_0 \cup L_1$ is not r.e.

Comment: this gave me a bit of clarity ..but how is L0'∩L1' is not empty for the first set ?  can u explain a bit more  will M be al the possible strings or only valid turing machine encodings?