# What are some examples of non-enumerable languages whose complement isn't either?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, turing-recognizable, recursively-enumerable

What are some examples of non-enumerable languages whose complement isn't either? I.e., a language L such that L is not Turning-recognizable and L’ is not Turing-recognizable either.

Update: Found some examples:

- [Is the below language Non R.E?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80924/is-the-below-language-non-r-e/80947)

Comment: $L_{0,1}=\{\langle M\rangle\mid M\text{ halts on } 0\text{ but not on } 1 \}$

Answer (score 2):

A random language is neither recognizable nor co-recognizable almost surely.

Every language which is complete for $\Sigma_k$ or $\Pi_k$, for any $k \geq 2$ (these are classes in the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy)), is neither recognizable nor co-recognizable. Some examples:

- The language of all oracle TMs $M$ such that $M$ halts on the empty input when given access to an oracle of the halting problem ($\Sigma_2$-complete).
- The language of all TMs $M$ such that $M$ halts on finitely many inputs ($\Sigma_2$-complete).
- The language of all TMs $M$ such that $M$ halts on all inputs ($\Pi_2$-complete).
- The language of all TMs $M$ such that "$M$ halts on $x$" is decidable ($\Sigma_3$-complete).
- The language of all TMs $M$ such that $M$ halts on all but finitely many inputs ($\Sigma_3$-complete).

See [lecture notes of Terwijn](https://dmg.tuwien.ac.at/kellner/teaching/2010SS_Grundbegriffe/Terwijn.pdf).