# Union of halting-like problem and non-halting-like problem

Tags: formal-languages, undecidability, halting-problem, semi-decidability

I came across the following problem:

> Define languages $L_0$ and $L_1$ as follows :
>
> $L_0=\{⟨M,w,0⟩∣M\text{ halts on }w\}$
> $L_1=\{⟨M,w,1⟩∣M\text{ does not halt on }w\}$
>
> Here $⟨M,w,i⟩$ is a triplet, whose first component $M$ is an encoding of a Turing Machine, second component $w$ is a string, and third component $i$ is a bit.
>
> Let $L=L_0∪L_1$. Which of the following is true?
>
> **A.** $L$ is recursively enumerable, but $\overline{L}$ is not
> **B.** $\overline{L}$ is recursively enumerable, but $L$ is not
> **C.** Both $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are recursive
> **D.** Neither $L$ nor $\overline{L}$ is recursively enumerable

I first felt that despite the bit as a third member of triple, $L_0$ is still equivalent to halting problem and $L_1$ is non halting problem. Union of halting and non halting problem is recursive as can be seen [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/80893). So, same will apply to the languages in the problem and their union will also be recursive, that is option C. But the answer given was D. So am guessing if its correct or not. I was not able to guess how that extra bit in the triple makes it different from halting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write formally what $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are:

$$L=\{\langle M,w,b \rangle| (b=0 \wedge M(w) \mbox{ halts}) \vee (b=1 \wedge M(w) \mbox{ does not halt}) \}$$

$$\overline{L}=\{\langle M,w,b \rangle| (b=1 \vee M(w) \mbox{ does not halt}) \wedge (b=0 \vee M(w) \mbox{ halts}) \}$$
The latter is confusing, so let's rearrange it:

$$\overline{L}=\{\langle M,w,b \rangle| (b=1 \wedge M(w) \mbox{ halts}) \vee (b=0 \wedge M(w) \mbox{ does not halt}) \}$$

(Note that we ignore malformed inputs, but that can be easily circumvented and does not effect the answer).

From this, you can easily see that $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are basically the same idea -- the bit at the end determines whether you're looking at the halting problem or at its complement. In either case, neither $L$ nor its complement are recursively enumerable.

One thing that can trigger you to suspect this is the answer, even without formally writing $\overline{L}$, is the fact that both the halting problem and its complement easily reduce to $L$. Thus, $L$ is not recongnizable nor co-recognizable, and so neither is its complement.

Comment: I didnt get your rearrangement. Are you doing (A+B)(C+D)=AD+BC ? If yes, is it valid? My main doubt is somewhat different. Union of halting and non halting problem is recursive. Then how just adding a bit to both of them make their union not recursive?

Comment: I'm applying the distributivity of $\vee$ over $\wedge$, but I eliminate the contradicting cases, such as $b=1\wedge b=0$. The second thing you wrote doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as a "halting language", and the union of a recognizable language and a non-recognizable language (if that's what you mean) can be anything -- either recognizable or not, depends on the languages.

Comment: [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/80893/113697) answer proves union of halting and non halting problem is decidable. I was asking whether $L_0\cup L_1$ is also decidable. If not, why? especially because they look very similar to halting and not halting problems, respectively.

Comment: Well, these are different problems. The bit at the end makes  a big difference. It makes it sort of a "disjoint union" rather than a standard union, which means that even after the union, you can tell which word comes from which language, as opposed to the question you linked to.

Comment: I am still struggling to get how union of halting and non halting problem is recursive, but adding extra bit to them make their union non recursive. The linked problem says, all we have to do is to check the encoding of input problem is of the form $\langle M,w\rangle$. Why adding extra bit makes such encoding check impossible? Is it because the bit indicates whether the string belongs to $L_0$ or $L_1$ and if it belongs to $L_1$ then we are supposed to check if $M$ does not halt on $w$ which is not possible as $L_1$ is not recursively enumerable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The bit makes this union "artificial". Perhaps think about it this way: suppose the halting problem is a white puzzle-piece, with a weird shape (i.e. a difficult problem). The non-halting problem is the complement white piece, which is also weird. But when you join them, you get a nice rectangle (i.e. an easy problem). However, when you have the extra bit, these pieces have different colors, so while you get a rectangle, it is not nice, and you can tell which piece is which.