# Some questions about the Computability of Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, church-turing-thesis

I'm learning for a test and I have some important questions about Computability of deterministic and non deterministic Turing Machines.

Consider we have the partial functions $f,g,h,t: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with $f$ is Turing Machine computable, $g$ not Turing Machine computable, $h$ is not While solvable and $t$ is While computable. Are the following answers correct? And is there anything changing if we had an non deterministic TM?

There is no proof to do words are ok :)

1. Is $f \circ g$ Turing Machine computable?
2. Is $g \circ f$ Turing Machine computable?
3. Is $t \circ h$ While computable?
4. Is $h \circ t$ While computable?

My answers:

First of all, we know that Turing Machine = While Computability. (#)

1. I would say, that we do not know if it is or is not TM computable, because there may a TM who can handle the output of an not TM computable function.
2. I would say no, because if whatever $g$ takes, it won't be TM computable.
3. and 4. Because  of (#) it is the same like 1. and 2.

Could that be right? It is for an multiple choice test and those questions are tricky.

Comment: I've never seen the terms "Turing Machine solvable" and "While solvable" used like this before. The first Google hit for `"while solvable" turing machine` is this question. Are these synonyms for "recursively enumerable"?

Comment: The fact that these are partial functions has me especially confused. Usually we say that a particular Turing machine or program _computes_ a partial function, but when we say that a function is or is not _computable_ we are talking about a total function.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg Hello, Turing Machine solvable is maybe the wrong word, I m a native speaker sry. Maybe it shout be known as Turing-computable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability   and for while programms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability

Comment: Maybe an example. If $m$ and $n$ are two partial functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and both are while computable than there composition is also while computable. If we now add a partial function $r$ $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ who is loop computable and we want to know if the composition of $r$ and $m$ (in any way) is loop computable than we can not find an answer, because a composition of an total and partial function do not need to be an total function, but loop is a total function, so problem. The result is of cource a partial funktion so it is while  and TM computable

Comment: I was still confused by your terminology until I searched around some more and discovered Uwe Schöning's [LOOP programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_(programming_language)), which can define exactly the primitive recursive functions, and [WHILE programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop#While_programming_language), which is Turing-complete. I think these are somewhat common in educational use, but they are not standard English mathematical terms, so I was confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "we don't know without more information" for all 4.

Suppose $f$ is the identity function $f(x) = x$. Then $f \circ g = g \circ f = g$, which is non-computable.

On the other hand, suppose $g$ is a *total* non-computable function (which is a special case of $g$ being a *partial* non-computable function), and suppose $f$ is the constant zero function $f(x) = 0$. In this case:

- $f \circ g$ is the constant zero function, which is obviously computable.
- $g \circ f$ is also a constant function. We don't necessarily know *what the constant is*, but that doesn't matter; every constant function is computable. See [How can it be decidable whether $\pi$ has some sequence of digits?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-can-it-be-decidable-whether-pi-has-some-sequence-of-digits)

Deterministic vs. non-deterministic Turing machine doesn't affect the answer, because a deterministic Turing machine can simulate the execution of a non-deterministic Turing machine (potentially with an exponential slowdown) by [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)).