# Can we find a Turing machine such that there is no Turing machine to decide whether it halts on $\epsilon$?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

The halting problem states that there is no Turing machine that can determine whether an arbitrary Turing machine halts on $\epsilon$. But I try to ask something different, can we find a specific Turing machine $M$ such that $L_M=\{ 0^n : M$ halts on $\epsilon \}$ is undecidable?
Or at least can we prove there exists such $M$?

The language itself isn't the issue, it is either $L=\{0^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ or $L=\phi$ and the way to distinguish the cases is only by the right side of the definition of $L$.

In other words, can we define a Turing machine such that we (or a Turing machine) can't determine whether it halts or not on $\epsilon$?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How can it be decidable whether π has some sequence of digits?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/367/8311)

Comment: Hang on a minute, what does $0^n$ mean in the definition of $L_M$?

Comment: A string of zeros of length $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you had such a TM, namely a machine $M$ for which the problem was "Does $M$ halt on empty input?" Certainly that problem would be decidable: one of two algorithms must be correct, (1) Answer "yes" or (2) Answer "no". The fact that we might not know which one is the correct algorithm is immaterial here; the only thing that matters is that we're sure *one* of the algorithms is the right one, so we know the problem is decidable. In more general terms, *any decision problem with a finite number of instances is decidable.*

Comment: Well, ok. Then I must ask, can we find a Turing machine to decide if a Turing machine decides $L$ for arbitrary $M$?

Comment: @oren1 For a given specific TM, yes, as I explained above; for an arbitrary TM, no, since that's just the blank tape halting problem, which we know is undecidable.